# Prevent right-click in iframe

Tags: iframe, right-click

I have used iframe to display image/pdf. i don't want the user to download by right clicking on image/pdf. so, i want to disable right-click option in iframe. please suggest me a way to achieve this

```
<div class="modal-body" id="iframeview" style="height:100%" >
    <iframe id="fr" src="/Content/Attachment/1053_Zaheer/98/DReference/1_3_2.jpg" style="width:98%;height:90%"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Preventing right click does not prevent a user to download your images or other content on your page. As soon as the content is loaded to the browser, the content is then already downloaded to the users machine.

Comment: No, it is not downloaded in user machine. if we right-click, browser will give 'save image as' etc. That's why i want to prevent right-click option

Comment: Yes, it is, otherwise user can't see the image. The only way to protect your content is not to publish it. Everything you load from your server is public. Now, ex. you'd had prevented right click, I'd open "Page info" dialog, there's a tab called "Media", which contains a list of all the images (and other media elements) on the page. I'd select an image, and clicked the "Save" button. And that's it, there's nothing you can do to prevent people to store the content you've loaded into their machine.

Comment: what do you mean by "page info" dialog?

Comment: The name depends on the browser and the language. If you open Tools menu, you can find the dialog from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
<div id="test" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <iframe id="fr" src="/Content/Attachment/1053_Zaheer/98/DReference/1_3_2.jpg" style="pointer-events:none;width:98%;height:90%"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can open the DevTools, and remove the `contextmenu` listener, and copy or save your image. You're just wasting your time when wiring these content "protections". A user can take a screenshot, they can run an external program which digs the image from the browser cache, or they use IE and run an ActiveX ... You can't simply prevent users to get the content saved.